# VsCode Snippet PlaceHolder default value File_Name_Base + uppercase

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

In the aim to gain some time in the future, I'm trying to create some snippets for VsCode.

There is the context. I have a `tmp.hpp` file in which I want to have

```
#ifndef TMP_HPP_
    #define TMP_HPP

#endif
```

My problem is, I want to be able to modify `TMP` by whatever I want. To do so I want it to be a default value
Finaly, if i decide to modify `TMP` by `WHATEVER` I want to force `WHATEVER` to be upcase.

To be more precise, i want my `${1}` to have default value : `${TM_FILE_BASE}` and I also want `${1}` and/or my `${TM_FILE_BASE}` to be `${/upper}`

Here is what i got for the moment :

```
"Creates a ifndef": {
    "prefix": "ifndef",
    "body": [
      "#ifndef ${${1:TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}}_HPP_",
      "  #define ${${1:TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}_HPP_",
      "",
      "#endif"
    ],
    "description": "Creates a basic ifndef"
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use nested variables:

```
"Creates a ifndef": {
    "prefix": "ifndef",
    "body": [
      "#ifndef ${1:${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}}_HPP_",
      "  #define ${1:${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}}_HPP_",
      "",
      "#endif"
    ],
    "description": "Creates a basic ifndef"
}
```

Pay attention to the `${1:${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}}` part. Here, `${1:...}` is the syntax for the placeholder, and thr `${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}` inside it specifies the variable that is modified with a regex-based replacement (all the contents are matched and captured into Group 1 with `/(.*)/` and replaced with the uppercased variant using `${1:/upcase}/}` (here, `$1` is the Group 1 value placeholder)).